# How to print http response first and do the heavy db operations later?

Tags: php, http, kohana-3

I'm implementing a mobile api. One of the requests processes json data and returns afterwards a predefined message( is independent from the calculation) back to the device. I'm using kohana 3.
How do I return the http response first and do the calculation afterwards?
What do you think about, using a message queue and a separate program that does the processing and db operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [gearman](http://gearman.org). There is a Kohana  [gearman module](https://github.com/managedit/kohana-gearman) made by one of the Kohana devs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can help flush() function, which send buffer (and header also). But flush() don't guarantee header send, because between php and web browser stays a web server (like apache)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but if you want to buffer output you can use [`ob_start()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like

```
ignore_user_abort(true)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

After making the call you can send your response back to the browser and finish wrapping up your calculations/logging after the connection is closed and the client is off doing something else.

This enables you to do some quick processing without hanging up the client or having to use an external process to handle your tasks